# RDLC showing additional Rows in a table

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I am creating a Report on RDLC. Lets say i have 2 tables in database where im importing data from users and expenses.

Each user can have multiple Expenses. Expenses contain Details and amount just 2 columns that i have to include in the report.

Ive created a stored procedure but its duplicating rows because of having same UserId in expenses. So far im able to achieve this.

[See This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG05r.png)

What i wanted is that One row with column bulty id and other details with multiple sub rows of expenses.

How can i achieve this. I've tried hide duplicate property in RDLC but its showing duplicate column fields

This is what i wanted to achieve

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPW7N.png)

Comment: Please show some sample data as it come out of your stored proc and the expected results based on the same sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing the Master/Detail Approach. Put 2 tablix in the list. on the first tablix set user details and made a row group so that the values dont repeat and then on the second tablix used the additional data fields.

Then dragged this additional data tablix into the row of first tablix and everything seems to work just fine.

For serial numbering i used Counting distinct values according to my userid

Answer (score 0):

in this case, I use matrix tool  in RDL file.
you should set expenses  the ColumnGroup of the matrix

Comment: Column group on the basis of?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15